# $\Lambda f\ge 0\iff f\ge 0$ if $\Lambda$ is a Gaussian convolution kernel?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Consider $\Lambda f(x)=\int_{\mathbb R} f(x-y) e^{-y^2} dy$. Suppose that for a bounded function $f$, $\Lambda f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Does it imply that $f\ge 0$ almost surely?

Answer (score 6):

No.

Take $f = 1 - g$ where $g$ is a non-negative function with tiny $L^1$ but large $L^\infty$. Then $\Lambda f(x) = \sqrt{\pi} - \Lambda g(x)$, and we also have

$$ \|\Lambda g\|_{L^\infty} \leq \|g\|_{L^1} \|e^{-y^2}\|_{L^\infty} \ll 1$$

so $\Lambda f(x) \geq 0$.

---

For concreteness, take $g(x)$ to be $100$ on $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ and $0$ otherwise, and adjust $\epsilon$ small enough.